# Installing Sphinx with MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to install the Sphinx with MySQL 5.7 I have downloaded the tarball from Sphinx site whenever I am runnig this command `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx --with-mysql` I am getting this error.

```
configuring Sphinx
------------------

checking whether to use dynamic linking for DB drivers... no
checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads... -pthread
checking for LIBS needed for pthreads... -lpthread
checking for pthreads... found
checking for pthread_mutex_timedlock... yes
checking whether to compile with MySQL support... dynamic
checking for mysql_config... mysql_config
checking for mysql_real_connect... no
checking for mysql_real_connect... no
checking MySQL include files... configure: error: missing include files.

******************************************************************************
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
   your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.
******************************************************************************
```

I have tried with installing this `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' still it doesn't I have even tried with supplying the MySQL include files path still it doesn't work. can anyone what causing this error ? I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Installing mysql-devel helped me for centos `sudo yum install mysql-devel`.
Suppose that for ubuntu package name is same.

Comment: I have tried this installing on ubuntu `sudo apt-get mysql-devel` unfortunately I get this error `E: Unable to locate package mysql-devel`

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: I have tried this earlier it is saying I already have latest.

Comment: What is the output for `mysql_config`?

Comment: this is what I get `/usr/bin/mysql_config`  along with the options we can use.